# How to refresh the page after closing p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, page-refresh

I've the below dialog:

```
<h:form id="r1">
  <p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
  <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
    <h:outputText id="test" value="Welcome to PrimeFaces" />
  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

How can I refresh the JSF page after closing the dialog?

Comment: See here also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150042/1599699 `window.location.replace(window.location.href)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<p:dialog>` supports the ajax `close` event. This only requires it being placed inside a `<h:form>` (on contrary to [the general recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053574)), so you need to make sure that it's already manually poisitioned to the very end of the `<h:body>` and that you don't make use of `appendToBody`.

```
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>

    ...

    <h:form>
        <p:dialog>
            <p:ajax event="close" update=":content" />
            ...
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Use if necessary `update="@all"` if you intend to update the **entire** page. But better is to update only the parts which really need to be updated.

Comment: Please <p:dialog/> has to be inside of <h:form/> or viceversa?

Comment: If you try to put `<h:form> ` outside your dialog

Comment: @BalusC, what if I open dialog with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog` as a separate page, so I don't have p:dialog. Can I add ajax via `options`?