# Primefaces commandButton is not showing dialog after ajax form refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I need your help and guidance on fixing the issue of showing the `dialog` after refreshing the form by using ajax. I am having a `dataTable` that it is showing a number of requests and onclick of the `commandButton` view, a `dialog` will be shown that contains some information. And onclose of the `dialog`, the form will be refreshed and the dataTable will get the updated information from the database. However for the first time, the dialog will be shown and the form will be refreshed by closing the `dialog`.

If I tried to click again on the view `commandButton` on the second time, the `commandButton` will not show any dialog and will not seem to do an action. Even the log it is not showing anything.

Here is my xhtml:

```
<h:form id="Requests">
    <p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" value="#{hrd.pendingRequests}"
            filteredValue="#{hrd.filteredPendingRequests}">
        <p:column headerText="Req. Date" sortBy="#{hr.requestDate}"
                filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{hr.requestDate}">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestDate}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">View</f:facet>
            <p:commandButton id="submitbutton" update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName} "
                    oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    title="View">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dialog id="CertificateDialog" header="Cert1" widgetVar="CertificateDialog">
        <p:ajax event="close" update=":Requests" listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

This method will be called onclose of the `dialog` .The UpdateDatatable method code is:

```
listPendingRequests.clear();
listPendingRequests = new ArrayList<PendingRequests>();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
String sql = "";

try {
    con = DBConn.getInstance().getConnection("jdbc/hr");

    // SQL Statement
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
        PendingRequests pendingList = new PendingRequests();

        requestDate = result.getString("REQ_DT");

        pendingList.setRequestDate(requestDate);

        listPendingRequests.add(pendingList);

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("Requests");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.print(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs have a special treatment in HTML DOM and JavaScript. You should never be ajax-updating any of the dialog's parents while still in the same view. Otherwise you potentially end up with duplicate dialogs and conflicts in JS. Moreover, the [strong recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053468/button-in-dialog-inside-pdialog-is-not-caling-controller-method/29053574#29053574) is to give each dialog its own form as in `<p:dialog><h:form>` to avoid confusion and misuse by starters, but as you'd like to use ajax close event on it, [you can't get around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107167/how-to-refresh-the-page-after-closing-pdialog/30107226#30107226) to use `<h:form><p:dialog>` instead. However, you placed other stuff in the very same form and you're even ajax-updating it. This is not right.

Tie the form to the dialog itself and don't put other stuff on it. In other words, split the current form.

```
<h:form id="requests">
    <p:dataTable ...>
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <p:dialog ...>
        <p:ajax event="close" ... update=":requests" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```